# Wordpress list pages by parents

Tags: php, wordpress

I need some help doing a navigation for my site but I couldn't figure out how to do it using Wordpress' `wp_list_pages()` function.

For reference, the navigation system on http://www.rwgroup.com/ should give the exact idea of what I am aiming for.

Before I tried using `wp_list_pages('child_of='.$post->parent_post)` but it seems that the pages only display wrt it's immediate parent and forgotten it's ancestors. I've been trying this out for a while now but I just couldn't get my head around it.

Any ideas would be great

Comment: Oh, and if it makes it easy on any of you, the site depth goes down to three which I would say is quite shallow, so if there are quick cheats or tricks around this, that would be most preferable. Thanks guys.

Comment: You may wish to post this in the WordPress Stack Exchange http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to list out current page with its ancestors and children-

```
<?php
//if the post has a parent
if($post->post_parent){
  //collect ancestor pages
  $relations = get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
  //get child pages
  $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = $post->ID AND post_type='page'" );
  if ($result){
    foreach($result as $pageID){
      array_push($relations, $pageID->ID);
    }
  }
  //add current post to pages
  array_push($relations, $post->ID);
  //get comma delimited list of children and parents and self
  $relations_string = implode(",",$relations);
  //use include to list only the collected pages. 
  $sidelinks = wp_list_pages("title_li=&echo=0&include=".$relations_string);
}else{
  // display only main level and children
  $sidelinks = wp_list_pages("title_li=&echo=0&depth=1&child_of=".$post->ID);
}

if ($sidelinks) { ?>
  <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  <ul>
    <?php //links in <li> tags
    echo $sidelinks; ?>
  </ul>         
<?php } ?>
```